# Calculate tax by city

Tags: magento

Is there a way for Magento to calculate sales tax based on the combination of city and zip code instead of zip code only? The problem is, there are many different tax rates within the 5-digit zip code. In some places there are even different tax rates within the same city code.

It seems I can't find the best solution out there. I'm sure many people will have the same issues like mine. Mind to share the solutions here?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it doesn't feel on topic for Stack Overflow to me, it's more like a plugin request. Have you tried Magento's community support forums?

Answer (score 3):

I think one city can have many zip codes, but one zip code can't have many cities right? You can map the tax rate to Country-State-Zipcode and it should be fine, what's the problem?

Or else, you will need to extend Tax module for implementing City as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. As a matter of fact, one zip can have several county and city codes.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of magento tax by city module we can able to manage the tax based the city also. 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tax-by-city-1.html